# Rule of voice names in Bing Text to Speech

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have a question about Bing Text to Speech API.

There are lots of supported voices at [Supported locales and voice fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput#SupLocales).

Some voice names have suffixes like **", Apollo"** or **"RUS"**.
It would be great if you let me know what do they mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get answer from Azure product team.

> **RUS** indicates models based on the concatenative synthesis technology, which is normally higher fidelity, more natural and *slightly* bigger latency.
>
> **Apollo** is just an internal service tag and customers can simply ignore that.

**Update:**

Ignore that means that you don't need to care about the mean of 'Apollo'. But still need to use (tja-JP, Ayumi, Apollo).

Comment: Thank you for the information. But I tried without ", Apollo" and got an error below.

Voice Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (ja-JP, Ayumi) not supported for url: https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize

It looks we can't ignore that.

Comment: @MitsuhiroSETOGUCHI. `Ignore that` means that you don't need to care about the mean of 'Apollo'.  But still need to use (tja-JP, Ayumi, Apollo)